# Accessing remote server service via HTTPS

Tags: https, remote-server, supervisord

I have a server(AWS) to which I have ssh access.
There is a service(supervisor) running on this service on port 9001 whose web view can be accessed through 127.0.0.1:9001 had it been a local machine.

But since it is not a local machine, how do I access it?

I got the ip address of the machine using `ifconfig | grep inet` and then tried accessing it through `https://172.11.11.1:9001/`
Bit dint work.

When I tried `wget https://172.11.11.1:9001/` it shows 
`Connecting to 172.31.19.8:9001...` and hangs there.

I have added the following line in my supervisor conf file.

```
[inet_http_server]
port = *:9001
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a server config question. You'll most likely find your AWS access properties allow connections on post 22, 80 and 443 only. In AWS console you'll need to add a new security access group to allow port 9001 to be accessed.

Comment: Is there any way I can proxy it through nginx?

Comment: Yes. 10 seconds in Google gets you there!. Have a look at "Set Up Nginx as a Reverse Proxy Server" https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04 - it points to a Node application but the config is the same, just change to port 9001